# Matter.js disable collision between different composites

Tags: javascript, physics-engine, matter.js

I am trying to use collision filtering as described in the ["Matter.js body documentation"](http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_collisionFilter). However, for my project I need to disable collisions between different Composite objects. So only bodies that are in the same composite should collide. I plan on having more then 32 Composites (32 is the maximum amount of collision categories provided by Matter.js). How would I achieve this?

```
// module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Body = Matter.Body,
    Vector = Matter.Vector,
    Composite = Matter.Composite,
    Constraint = Matter.Constraint,
    MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// create a renderer
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var canvas = document.getElementById("maincanvas");

var render = Render.create({
    element: container,
    canvas: canvas,
    engine: engine,
    options: {
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        wireframes: false
    }
});

// This makes collision much easier to test
engine.world.gravity = {x:0, y:0};

// Add a mouseconstraint to test
var mc = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
    element: render.canvas
});
Composite.add(engine.world, mc);

var bodies1 = []
var bodies2 = []
var xpos = 30
var ypos = 30
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    bodies1.push(Bodies.circle(xpos, ypos, 10, {
        collisionFilter: {
            group:-1
        },
        render: {
            fillStyle: "blue"
        }
    })
    );
    xpos += 30;
}
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    bodies2.push(Bodies.circle(xpos, ypos, 10, {
        collisionFilter: {
            group:-1
        },
        render: {
            fillStyle: "red"
        }
    })
    );
    xpos += 30;
}

var composite1 = Composite.create();
Composite.add(composite1, bodies1);
var composite2 = Composite.create();
Composite.add(composite2, bodies2);

Composite.add(engine.world, [composite1, composite2]);

Engine.run(engine);
Render.run(render);
```

This way I am able to disable collision between the composites, but this also disables collision 'inside' the composite. I could do this with the `collisionFilter.category` system but how would that work with more then 32 composites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for collision filtering at the composite level, you'll need to handle it at the body level. To make this easier to manage, just create some composite helper functions e.g. `compositeSetCollisionFilter(composite, filter)` and iterate over `Composite.allBodies(composite)`.

Regarding the limit of 32 categories, this is due to a [bitwise implementation](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/src/collision/Detector.js#L100-L105) (for performance supposedly, though I doubt it matters much in reality). I've raised an issue on the project about [reconsidering this](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/341).

For now there's a way to have more though if you replace [Matter.Detector.canCollide(filterA, filterB)](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/src/collision/Detector.js#L100-L105) with your own function that can compare two `body.collisionFilter` objects. With this you can use what ever scheme you like for `body.collisionFilter` objects.